# What should I ask my DBA in order to diagnose a slow application?

Tags: sql-server

I am working in the IT department of an industrial firm. The IT department is a handful of people, mainly project managers, and everything else is outsourced.

I have been managing a project, where a third party application has been bought off the shelf, and deployed by the vendor, but to be maintained on our own.

It consists of a central application server, connected to an SQL Server database, and a dozen heavy clients, all on our premises, on the same VLAN.

Most of the time, it runs fine, however, sometimes, when accessing records from the DB, the application is awfully slow.

I have been asking our DBA (outsourced) what is wrong, but have been responded by something along the lines of `"Please ask me to do something with the DB, and I'll gracefully do it"`.

Hence the question, **in a situation of sporadic sluggishness like this, which technical actions should I ask of my DBA to make progress on the case?**

Please monitor the performance of the DB is apparently too vague, and they expect something along the lines of 'Enable this performance counter for that long' and so on...

Comment: Ideally you should find a new DBA, one that doesn't need another DBA to explain to him/her  basic DBA functions.

Comment: Its entirely possible there is something outside SQL Server on the same machine...check Task Manager during a slow period.  Aside from that, ask your "DBA" to set up some logging, or extended events so they will have history to look at after the next slow event.  If they can't do that...well...you know...:)

Comment: My god fire that guy. If you tell me " hey the app is slow, can you help me?" I would say " sure". and i would run some traces, sp_whoisactive, I would use Perfmon and etc. personally you just need to say " app is slow doing this" and I would do my job (KungFury Voice).

Comment: Fire that mofo ASAP! `"Please ask me to do something with the DB, and I'll gracefully do it"` isn't exactly proactive! Send an email to that pitiful excuse for a "DBA" saying "I think our relationship has blossomed to the extent that I wish to take things up a notch - could you send me a photo, I'd like to nominate you for an award!" - when they excitedly ask (as they will because incompetent half-wits always think they're doing a good job!) "what award", you can send them this link: [Not my Job Award](https://digitalsynopsis.com/buzz/not-my-job-funny-pics/)! Bonne chance!

Answer (score 9):

While a good DBA can find out a lot on his own, it never hurts to give a lot of information.

- Which application you're using. If you know server/db ect give that as well.
- Test/Prod
- When the issue occurs, eg. I open this form and it's slow, or when I do this...
- What's slow and what's fast. For some applications it can be perfectly acceptable to wait 1-2 seconds, while others have to perform near instantly. It can often be really easy to get a first bump in performance, but after that it takes a lot longer to make it just a little bit faster
- Which login you're using

Especially if he's external + perhaps a junior it never hurts to just give him all you've got.

After that it's mostly up to the DBA to setup monitoring.

- Log WhoIsActive to a table
- Use the build in query store if version is 2016 or higher
- Buy a third party tool, eg. SentryOne/Red gate monitor

After he setup monitoring you could also mail him "I'm having issues right now, could you see if you notice anything special?" Do not expect him to reply right away, but it gives him a window that he can check later where he knows the issue occurred.

Comment: +1 on this. As in all calls for tech support, sometimes it helps to just walk them through on what you're doing when you notice the problem. Don't just say "It's slow"

Answer (score 2):

> Most of the time, it runs fine, however, sometimes, when accessing records from the DB, the application is awfully slow.

Interesting - and accurate - turn of phrase, there.

The *Application* is suffering poor performance. 
It is unknown, at this point, whether the *Database* is (or not).

Generally speaking, *Databases* don't run slowly - *Queries* do.

You need to identify those queries that are running poorly and then obtain, either yourself or via your DBA, the Execution Plan for those queries.  Analyse these and see where improvements can be made.

Whilst your DBA could spend *days* mucking about with server-side settings to obtain [maybe] 2-3 *percentage points* improvement, improving your queries, changing table indexing or even restructuring your data could gain you *Orders of Magnitude* improvement!

That said, the DBA's response fills me horror.
They should at least be able to make some auggestions of things that you could look at but, sadly, it looks as though you've got someone that will "fix" the database if it actually *breaks*, but have neither the time, interest, inclination or [possibly] knowledge to do anything more.  If that is the case, they will be of *very little* use in getting to the bottom of this problem.

Comment: I've never even heard of a pure "Database Administrator" in the wild before.  Usually we are a blend (somewhere on a line) of Administrator / Developer / Tuning.  It does sound like they are a pure "Administrator".  That may be either the contract with the third party or just this one person.  But the DBA on the other end should be able to provide at minimum the log counters that are already tracked, such as PLE, disk performance, cpu, verification of index maintenance, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to ask is for the DBA to enable the [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15), and grant you the VIEW DATABASE STATE permission.  This will track query performance and give you the ability to identify slow-running queries with SSMS.

Comment: Assumes SQL 2016+, right?

Comment: Yes.  SQL Server 2016+.

Answer (score 1):

You want to get your hands on Brent Ozar's First Responder Kit, free to download here:

https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/

you'll get a bunch of diagnostic scripts that should point you in the right direction.

Start with sp_blitzfirst, then sp_blitz, then see where life takes you.

Answer (score -2):

In fairness to the OP, I have yet to see project managers that are technically adept at tuning an application; that is not their job. But if I feed them the information they need, they can help coordinate with others (like the vendors or developers or end users).

As a DBA when my "customers" tell me that an application is slow, I don't tell them to "tell me what to do, and I will do it". I come back with questions that will help me tune it, and drive the tuning effort from there. Questions like what application, what was it trying to do, what time of the day, etc.

Best case, my monitoring tools will help identify performance issues for me. A case of non-repeatable, intermittent performance issue is difficult to troubleshoot and that's when performance monitors help.

Worst case, I will need to profile the application while it is running slow. This gets tricky if it is not consistently repeatable.

Answer (score -3):

First thing you can do is figure out on your end what specifically causes this to kick off the slowness.

1. Is the number of clients
2. Is running a reports from multiple clients
3. Is it a network issue if the SQL server is in the cloud....
4. etc....

Armed with that information you can then tell the remote DBA  monitor the database and we will cause the slowness

Read over this link  about finding slow queries
https://serverfault.com/questions/182665/does-mssql-server-have-the-equivalent-of-mysqls-query-logs

Comment: this is not his job. he's not the DBA.